# Why exception must be declared?

Tags: c++, exception

It is recognized that, in C++ for example, if a method throws an exception, it must be declared. ￼ But the compelling reason why such rule has to be applied seems to be less known for some people (I asked some colleagues, no convincing answers).

Can someone explains to me, maybe from the compiler side, that why we absolutely need to declare exception in methods that throw it? Thanks.

Comment: "It is recognized that, in C++ for example, if a method throws an exception, it must be declared" - are you sure about that?

Comment: @user2357112 Anyway, an exception has to be caught or declared... What is your point?

Comment: @zell you mean specifying what exception a function may throw? That's deprecated, except for `noexcept` in C++11 or `throw()` in C++98/03.

Comment: [There is no such requirement.](http://ideone.com/XHWOue)

Comment: @user2357112 Your example does not throw an exception, or more specifically, an Exception class.

Comment: @zell you can throw just about anything in C++, doesn't have to be an exception.

Comment: @zell, see also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114338/why-are-exception-specifications-bad for a nice discussion why exception specification were deprecated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have already stated, you *don't* need to put exception specifications on functions (via `throw()`, which was deprecated in C++11). This is a requirement of Java (i.e checked exceptions, as they're called).

However, what you can do in C++11 is mark functions to be `noexcept`, meaning that they won't throw. This gives the compiler some freedom to optimize some things it otherwise won't be able to because it doesn't know whether the function can throw or not. The consequences of using `noexcept` specifications on functions would be that if they somehow do throw, `std::terminate` will be called, effectively "crashing" your application. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `noexcept` also means that if the function actually does let an exception escape, go directly to `terminate`, go directly to `terminate`, do not pass Go, do not collect $200.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why exception specification were deprecated is the following. Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

void h() // no exception specification
{
    throw double(0); // throws double
}

void f() throw(int)
{
    h(); // suppose we were sure that h() doesn't throw
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch (int)
    {
        std::cout << "int exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Other exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Suppose that we believe that `f()` only throws `int`, so we specify this via an exception specification. However, `f()` uses some third-party library function `h()`, which we don't have control on (here we defined it, but in real code you may assume that `h()` is invoked via a shared library). Now, in ver. 0.1 of the library, we knew that `h()` didn't throw (or maybe threw only `int`), so we could use it safely in our code for `f()`. However, the library developers believed that it's a good idea to throw a `double` in some cases, so they modified `h()` which now throws a `double` (and we blindly upgraded our library so now we have the "new" `h()`.

Now you see what will happen: `h()` throws a `double` inside `f()`. However, `f()` is marked as `throw(int)`, so all bets are off, the program ends up calling `terminate`, bam.

Note that by not specifying at all `throw(int)`, we could have caught the `double` exception via the last `catch(...)` block.

This is only one of the reasons exception specifications are considered "bad practice" and were deprecated, due to this kind of code breaking. There are more contrived examples also, and a searching on your favorite search engine reveals some very good answers.

Comment: Well, it technically calls `unexpected`, which calls the corresponding handler, which calls `terminate` by default.